# how to automatically update column based on the second layer, trigger, postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers, qgis

I am newbie in postgreSQL. I have 2 tables, observation and landcover, i want to create a trigger which would allowed to update the column observation.land based on the spatial information according to the second layer (table) landcover.code_06.

I mean, If I update point layer observation in QGIS , I want to have in the attribute table same information in column LAND as in the column CODE_06.

I've created this, but i have no idea, what's wrong or why it doesn't work.

---

```
ALTER TABLE observation ADD COLUMN land varchar (20)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION landinfo_land()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN
    NEW.land := observation.land

                  FROM observation.land AS b, landcover.code_06 AS  w
          WHERE w.geom && NEW.geom AND
ST_Intersects(ST_PointOnSurface(NEW.geom), b.geom);
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION landinfo_land() OWNER TO postgres;


CREATE TRIGGER update_land_value
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON observation
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE landinfo_land();
```

Comment: Just a guess: `SELECT observation.land INTO NEW.land FROM ...`

Comment: x-post to http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/127593/12379

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
 NEW.land := observation.land

                  FROM observation.land AS b, landcover.code_06 AS  w
          WHERE w.geom && NEW.geom AND
ST_Intersects(ST_PointOnSurface(NEW.geom), b.geom);
```

doesn't make any sense.

It looks like you're attempting to use a subquery rather than a simple expression, but there's no `SELECT` keyword. You can't do that, even in PL/PgSQL. It must be a valid query if it isn't just a simple expression with no SQL query keywords.

Try:

```
 SELECT INTO STRICT NEW.land  observation.land
 FROM observation.land AS b, landcover.code_06 AS  w
 WHERE w.geom && NEW.geom AND
 ST_Intersects(ST_PointOnSurface(NEW.geom), b.geom);
```

Yes, the syntax is ugly.

If you continue to have issues, examine the PostgreSQL server error logs. They will contain error messages indicating what's going wrong when executing your PL/PgSQL function, which will help you find what else is wrong.